# difference in mongodb update/upsert performance between collections and capped collections

Tags: java, performance, mongodb

I have been playing a bit with mongoDb to check its performance. I have created a little test in Java with one small collection:

```
 public class ClientWord {

@Id
private ObjectId id;
@Field(value="client_id")
private ObjectId clientId;
private String   text;
private int      value;
    ....
```

This document has a double compound index:

```
> db.client_words.getIndexes()
[
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "test1.client_words",
    "name" : "_id_"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "client_id" : 1,
        "text" : 1
    },
    "unique" : true,
    "ns" : "test1.client_words",
    "name" : "client_id_1_text_1"
}
]
```

My test inserts 100.000 documents:

```
    public void test(){
    int size = 10;
    List<ObjectId> clientIds = createClientIds(size);
    t1 = t2 = t3 = new Date();
    printWithTime("Inserting...    ");

    for (int i=0; i<10000; i++){
        for (ObjectId id : clientIds){
            mongoTemplate.upsert(
                    Query.query(Criteria.where("text").is("text"+i).and("client_id").is(id)), 
                    Update.update("text","text"+i).set("client_id",id).inc("value", 3), 
                    ClientWord.class);
        }
        if(i%100 == 0){
            System.out.printf("\t%6d\t",i*size);
            printWithTime("");
        }
    }

    printWithTime("Total time: ");
    System.out.println("Total elements in the ddbb: "+mongoTemplate.count(new Query(), ClientWord.class));
}
```

I have try this code with normal and capped collections. With normal took more than 10 minutes and with capped 20 seconds. I also found that capped does constant time insertions while normal collections takes longer and longer while the collection is growing, I guess because the index size but both collections have the same indexes...

Can anybody explain me why there is so big difference? Any trick to improve the normal collection performance?

Comment: Are you sure you actually update the capped collection and not just insert? Plus capped collection is pre-alloced whereas a normal collectiojn isn't, etc etc, though 10 mins on 10,000 records is stupid. What setup have you got? Is it just a single mongod?

Comment: how big did you make your capped collection?  And you might want to fix your title, you are doing inserts and not updates.  Note that doing actual inserts rather than upserts would be faster.  You have unnecessary extra lookup.

Comment: @Sammaye, AsyaKamsky you both are right I was just inserting documents but i wanted to check the performance with the upsert option so I will fix the title to be more acurated.

Sammaye My mongo is set with the default configuration. I didn't change anything

Comment: @AsyaKamsky My capped collection is 50Mb big. Do you think find and insert/update will be quicker than update/upsert?

Comment: why do you need to find?  You are just doing a simple insert.  What does a count print at the end on the capped collection?  I suspect that maybe your small capped size is limiting things to holding only a subset of the documents you are inserting.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky in the future i will have many machines writing to this collection. In case the unique index already exists I need to increment its value. This is why i need to look for it first of all. About the size print you are right it was to control that the capped collection size was enough and also to check when I run this test twice I don't have 200.000 documents